# Using YAML pipeline to deploy Azure Function

Tags: azure-functions, azure-pipelines

I'm trying to build and deploy an Azure Function using YAML pipelines. The build and publish stage works fine, it produces a zip file which I can download.
However my deployment stage keeps failing with the following error: No package found with specified pattern: D:\a\1\drop\output.zip

I've tried using different environment variables and back/forward slash in the path.

Note, that the vmImageName is set to 'windows-latest'

Output of the deployment stage:

- Downloading: D:\a\1/drop/output.zip
- Error: No package found with specified pattern:  D:\a\1\drop\output.zip

What am I missing?

Build and publish stage:

```
- stage: Build
  displayName: Build solution
  jobs:  
  - job: Build
    displayName: Build and publish solution
    pool:
      vmImage: $(vmImageName)
      workspace:
            clean: all
    steps:
    - checkout: self
    - checkout: AzureUtil

    - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
      displayName: Build and Publish Azure Function
      inputs:
        command: publish
        arguments: '--configuration Release --output publish_output'
        projects: $(projectsPath)/$(projectFileName)
        publishWebProjects: false
        modifyOutputPath: false
        zipAfterPublish: false

    - task: ArchiveFiles@2
      displayName: "Archive files"
      inputs:
        rootFolderOrFile: "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/publish_output"
        includeRootFolder: false
        replaceExistingArchive: true
        archiveFile: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)\output.zip'         

    - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
      displayName: "Publish build artifacts"
      inputs:
        PathtoPublish: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)\output.zip'
        artifactName: 'drop'
```

Deployment stage:

```
- stage: Deploy
  displayName: Deploy Azure Function
  dependsOn: Build
  condition: succeeded()
  jobs:
    - deployment: Deploy
      displayName: Deploy Azure Function
      pool:
        vmImage: $(vmImageName)
      environment: 'Web-Dev'
      strategy:
        runOnce:
          deploy:
            steps:
            - task: AzureFunctionApp@1
              displayName: 'Azure functions app deploy'
              inputs:
                azureSubscription: '$(serviceConnectionName)'
                appType: functionApp
                appName: '$(azureFunctionName)'
                package: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)\drop\output.zip'
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to Deploy Azure Function to Function app via YAML pipeline and it was successful.

Created a .Net Http Trigger in my Visual studio pushed the Code to Azure Devops Repository and used default YAML pipeline below:-

**Azure DevOps Repository:-**

[image]

**Default Pipeline:-**

[image]

**YAML pipeline code below referred from this [Github link](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-yaml/blob/master/templates/asp.net-core-functionapp-to-windows-on-azure.yml):-**

> ```yaml
> # .NET Core Function App to Windows on Azure
> # Build a .NET Core function app and deploy it to Azure as a Windows function App.
> # Add steps that analyze code, save build artifacts, deploy, and more:
> # https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/languages/dotnet-core
>
> trigger:
> - master
>
> variables:   # Azure Resource Manager connection created during
> pipeline creation   azureSubscription: 'xxxx-xxx-xxx-98e7-e2dxxxxx'
>
>   # Function app name   functionAppName: 'siliconfunc43'
>
>   # Agent VM image name   vmImageName: 'windows-2019'
>
>   # Working Directory   workingDirectory:  '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/FunctionApp8'
>
> stages:
> - stage: Build   displayName: Build stage
>
>   jobs:
>   - job: Build
>     displayName: Build
>     pool:
>       vmImage: $(vmImageName)
>
>     steps:
>     - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
>       displayName: Build
>       inputs:
>         command: 'build'
>         projects: |
>           $(workingDirectory)/*.csproj
>         arguments: --output $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/publish_output --configuration
> Release
>
>     - task: ArchiveFiles@2
>       displayName: 'Archive files'
>       inputs:
>         rootFolderOrFile: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/publish_output'
>         includeRootFolder: false
>         archiveType: zip
>         archiveFile: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip
>         replaceExistingArchive: true
>
>     - publish: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip
>       artifact: drop
>
> - stage: Deploy   displayName: Deploy stage   dependsOn: Build   condition: succeeded()
>
>   jobs:
>   - deployment: Deploy
>     displayName: Deploy
>     environment: 'development'
>     pool:
>       vmImage: $(vmImageName)
>
>     strategy:
>       runOnce:
>         deploy:
>
>           steps:
>           - task: AzureFunctionApp@1
>             displayName: 'Azure functions app deploy'
>             inputs:
>               azureSubscription: '$(azureSubscription)'
>               appType: functionApp
>               appName: $(functionAppName)
>               package: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/drop/$(Build.BuildId).zip'
> ```

**In the last step add:-**

```yaml
package: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/drop/$(Build.BuildId).zip'
```

**Output:-**

[image]

[image]

***Function got deployed and triggered successfully,*** Refer below:-

[image]

[image]