# How do I use DevOps to release multiple Azure Functions from the same project

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-functions, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I'm trying to assist a team in moving their deployment strategy of a number of legacy projects to use DevOps release pipelines. The APIs aren't a problem as I know that area well but I'm struggling with a C# Azure Functions project.

This project contains 3 separate Timer triggered functions, which have previously been deployed via manual webdeploy to 3 different Function Apps in Azure.

What I'm trying to figure out is how do I set up what I'm assuming would be 3 pipeline tasks that are needed to release from the same artifact to the 3 different function apps, selecting the correct class tagged with FunctionNameAttribute for each one.

I'm hoping I'm just missing something obvious but any help would be very gatefully received

Comment: > Use the same build artifact for different like here -https://i.imgur.com/03NQIld.png and create multiple azure function deploy task with different function apps like here- https://i.imgur.com/zSdbMxr.png

Comment: You can refer this SO thread answer of mine to build and deploy your Function app directly with YAML pipeline by using 3 different [AzureFunctionApp@1] tasks:- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76351919/using-yaml-pipeline-to-deploy-azure-function/76354948#76354948 > Or just build the Function and use the artifact in release pipeline as per my above comment

Comment: Hi @SiddheshDesai - Apologies if I'm being dim here, but how do you tell it which named function from the project to run in which function app in infrastructure (Functions really aren't an area I've done any significant work in before so I'm guessing I'm missing some fundamental concept)

Comment: Function app is one resource where you can deploy multiple functions (triggers HTTP, Blob storage trigger, Event grid trigger) etc. If you have multiple triggers you can deploy them in the same Function app. Or else deploy each triggers in different function app

Comment: You do not need 3 different pipeline tasks, Just Select which Which Function app you want to deploy your artifact in in the same release pipeline, With different Azure Function App deploy task, In that task, Select the respective function app as per my answer below

Comment: Many thanks @SiddheshDesai - My fundamental misunderstanding was that I needed a function app resource for each "FunctionName" (i.e. trigger). By deploying the project to one function app it has deployed all 3 triggers. Many thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

***I built one Azure Function with Artifact and created Release pipeline with 2 Function app deployments simultaneously and it was successful, Refer below:-***

Create a Build artifact with the Azure DevOps Yaml pipeline by **referring to my SO thread answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76351919/using-yaml-pipeline-to-deploy-azure-function/76354948#).**

**My Azure repository with Function code:-**

[image]

> If you have multiple Triggers in your Function code you can deploy them using the same steps given here in a single Function app which will contain your multiple triggers or a Multiple 3 Function app.

***Now use the Build Artifact generated from above So thread answer OR your Azure DevOps repository containing source code directly in your Release pipeline like below:-***

[image]

**Azure Repos:-**

[image]

**And configure Azure release pipeline task:-**

**Create 3 different tasks for your 3 Function apps, To deploy your function in 3 apps together like below:-**

**Selected functionapp85 in 1st Azure Function App Deploy task:-**

[image]

**Selected valleuyfunc542 in 2nd Azure Function App Deploy task:-**

[image]

Created the Release pipeline and the Functions were deployed in both the Function app like below:-

**Output:-**

**Function App 1:- (functionapp85)**

[image]

**Function App2:- (valleyfunc542)**

[image]

***Output:-***

[image]